# Is MySQL license needed to be used in an enterprise?

Tags: mysql, open-source, licensing

We are using Open Source MySQL for development purpose in our company. After the development is complete we are deploying out system with the MySQL database at the client site. The client is using the deployed system for the internal use limited to it's employees. Now do they need to pay for any license from MySQL? Can they continue using it for free?

Comment: No you do not need to buy the license. As long as you are using the mysql's open source version which is free to use for any commercial product.

Comment: Hi there! Your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow since it is not a direct, programming related issue, but rather about licensing. You may be able to get an answer at [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com). Be sure to read their on-topic page too. :D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing instead of directly about programming. [[See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1402846)] for details and the [[help]] for more.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is not OpenSource (GPL), your client have to buy a licence.

More information about licensing can be found here:

- Commercial licence: http://www.mysql.com/about/legal/licensing/oem/
- Open source exceptions: http://www.mysql.com/about/legal/licensing/foss-exception/

In the commercial licence page, you can find this question:

> **Q3:** As a commercial OEM, ISV or VAR, when should I purchase a commercial license for MySQL software?
>   **A:** OEMs, ISVs and VARs that want the benefits of embedding commercial binaries of MySQL software in their commercial applications
>   but do not want to be subject to the GPL and do not want to release
>   the source code for their proprietary applications should purchase a
>   commercial license from Oracle. Purchasing a commercial license means
>   that the GPL does not apply, and a commercial license includes the
>   assurances that distributors typically find in commercial distribution
>   agreements.

As far as I know, when you use a program under GPL, your work must be under GPL too (free and open source) except if it's a website which an exception.

Comment: We have not done any modification to the MySQL source code. We have just used it as a Database for our application. And we have sold our product to the client. Does my client still need to buy the license? I read the terms but couldn't clearly understand.